Smallest ball containing a finite set
Let $X = \{x_1,\dots, x_{d+1}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $B(y,r)$ be the smallest ball that contains $X$ with center $y$ and radius $r$.
$$
J = \left\{j \in \left\{1,\dots, d+1\right\} \ : \ \left\vert x_{j} - y\right\vert = r\right\}
$$

I would like to show that $y \in \operatorname{conv}\left(\left\{x_j \ : \ j \in J\right\}\right)$.
My strategy is is to note that one can shift the ball in an appropriate direction, and then shrink the ball to get a smaller ball that still contains the set $X$.
However, I have been having trouble writing this down carefully.
In two dimensions consider the following example:



However, even in this case, I'm not sure how to write down carefully why shifting the ball by $\epsilon n$ for some small $\epsilon$ we get that $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ are strictly contained in the ball ( I understand that we can conclude from this that we can then shrink the ball after we prove this, contradicting the minimality of the ball ).


Could you explain what you mean by "shifting the sphere by $\epsilon n$ specifically? $x_1$ for example will not be in the sphere, necessarily, if it is perturbed, as it lies on the boundary of the circle draw in the illustration.
I think what you're looking for is the convex hull of a set of points, which you can find a minimal "sphere" containing this convex hull.

Whoops sorry about this, I meant to say "ball" instead of "sphere".

Are you working in $\Bbb{R}^n$, or a general metric space?

Whoops sorry again, I just edited the post to say that $X \subset \mathbb{R}^d$

Are $R$ and $r$ related? Because o/w there needn't be any solution to $|x - y| = R$ in $X$.

Additionally, are $x_1, \cdots, x_{d+1}$ any $d +1$ points in $X$? Because if so, even if $R = r,$ I can explicitly choose points that lie on one side of a hyperplane lying away from $y$, right? E.g., take a bunch of points on the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ as $X$, and take three points with $x^1 > 0$ as the points under consideration.

@stochastiboy321 Thank you for all of your comments. I have edited the question again and so sorry again for all of the typos.

Getting the "appropriate direction" is the only tricky part. The hyperplane separation theorem might be helpful here. There is a hyperplane separating the convex hull of ${x_j,:,j\in J}$ from the center of the circle (a single point is also a convex set), if the center of the circle is not part of the convex hull. The normal vector on that hyperplane can be used as the direction for the shifting.

Denote the (closed) convex hull of the $x_j$, $j\in J$, by $C$. Let $\epsilon$ be positive and close to $0$ (how close, stay tuned).
Let $y$ be a vector.
Because $T :x\mapsto (1-\epsilon)x+\epsilon P_C(x)$ is firmly nonexpansive, where $P_C$ is the projection onto $C$, it follows that for all $c\in C$,
$$\|T(y)-c\|^2 \leq \|y-c\|^2 -\|y-T(y)\|^2.\quad (*)$$
Now assume that  $y$ is the solution to your problem and that $y\notin C$.
Then $(*)$ shows that $T(y)$ does strictly better than $y$ in terms of containing $X_J$, giving us a new, smaller, radius $r_J$ where $r_J$ is as close as we like to $r$ if $\epsilon$ is small enough. Also, $T(y)$ is as close as we want to $y$. Because the points in $X\setminus X_J$ lie in the interior of the $r$-ball centered at $y$, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, they will also lie in the $r_J$-ball centered at $T(y)$. This contradicts the assumption that $y$ is a solution.
Therefore, the solution must belong to $C$.

OP wants to show that $y$ is in the convex hull of ${x_j,:,j\in J}$, not in the convex hull of $X= {x_1,\ldots,x_{d+1}}.$

@ReinhardMeier Very true. I modified the argument.

An alternative approach going off of the suggestion in @Reinhard Meier's comment:
Let $X_J := \{x_j \ : \ j \in J\}$. Suppose that $y \notin \mathrm{conv}(X_J)$. Then as both $\{y\}$ and $\mathrm{conv}(X_J)$ are compact, the hyperplane separation theorems give us that there exists a hyperplane $H$ that strictly separates $\{y\}$ from $\mathrm{conv}(X_J)$.
So there exists an $\alpha > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ where
$$
H := \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d \ : \ \langle x, n \rangle = \alpha \},
$$
and
$$
\langle n,c \rangle > \alpha > \langle n, y \rangle \qquad \text{for all } c \in \mathrm{conv}(X_J).
$$
Now let $\epsilon > 0$ be a small constant to be determined later. Observe that for all $c \in \mathrm{conv}(X_J)$ we have
\begin{align*}
\|(y+ &\epsilon n) - c \|^2 < \|y - c\|^2 \\
&\iff 
\|y + \epsilon n\|^2 - 2\Big( \langle y,c \rangle + \epsilon \langle n,c \rangle \Big) + \|c\|^2 < \|y\|^2 - 2\langle y,c \rangle + \|c\|^2 \\
&\iff 2\epsilon \Big(\underbrace{\langle n,y\rangle - \langle n,c\rangle}_{< 0} \Big) + \epsilon^2 \|n\|^2 < 0,
\end{align*}
which is true for small enough $\epsilon$.
